# Developing always running PHP script

Tags: php, console

(Our server is Linux based)

I'm an experienced PHP developer but first time i'll develop a bot which always running and fetch some datas.

I'll explain my application with a simple (**and sample**) scenario. I have about 2000 web site url and my application will visit this url's and record contents of web page's . This application will work 7 days 24 hours. It will start working again when it's finish 2000 web sites.

But i need some suggestions for my server. As you see, my application will be run *infinity* until i shut down server. I can do this *infinity loop* with this :

```
while(true)
{
     APPLICATION CODES HERE
}
```

But i think this will be an evil for server :) Is it possible to doing something like this, on server side?

Also i think using *cronjobs* but it's not work for my scenario. Because my script start working again asap it's finish working. I have to "**start again when you finish your work**" , not "**start every 30 minutes**" . Because i don't know, maybe fetching all 2000 websites, will take more than 30 minutes or less than 30 minutes.

I hope i explained it very well.

Also i'm worried about memory usage. As you know garbage collector cleans memory after every  PHP script stop. But as i said, my app won't stop for days (maybe weeks) . So garbage collector won't be triggered. I'm manually unsetting ([unset() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)) all used variables at end of script. Is it enough?

I need some suggestions from server administrators :)

**PS.** I'm developing it as console application, not a web application. I can execute it from command line.

Comment: This is really a question for [StackOverflow] as it primarily concerns the architecture of your application. Frankly, the idea of doing it all inside a deliberately infinite loop is absolutely terrible, but I think you know that!

Comment: This sounds like a question for our sister site [programmers.se].

Comment: I'm worrying about server because of this i asked here :) But as you said, it can be a SO question, too.

Comment: @EdHeal , seriously, i couldn't understand what you mean, because of my English.

Answer (score 0):

Batch processing.. store all the sites in a csv or something, mark them after completion, then work on all the ones non-marked, then work on all the marked.. etc. Only do say 1 or 5 at a time, initiate batch script every minute from cron..

Don't even try to work on all of them at once.. any errors and you won't know what happened..

Could even store the jobs in a database, store processing stats etc.. allows for fine-tuning and better reporting.

You will probably hit time-limits trying to run infinite php scripts, even from the command line.. also your server admin will hate you. Will probably run into Memory limits if you don't release resources properly.. far too easily done with php.

Read: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-batch/

Answer (score 0):

Your script could just run through the list once and quit. That way, what ever resources php is holding can be freed.

Then have a shell script that calls the php script in an infinite loop.

As php is not designed for long running task, I am not sure if the garbage collection is up to the task. Quiting after every run will force it to release everything.